# C++ inject member variable only if template arguments are present

Tags: c++, design-patterns, graph, c++20

I'm writing a simple generic Graph class, referencing the Boost.Graph implementation.

The implementation is like this:

```
template <typename GraphTraits, typename... Properties>
class Graph {
public:  
  using vertex_type = GraphTraits::vertex_type;
  using vertex_iterator = GraphTraits::vertex_iterator;
  
  using edge_type = GraphTraits::edge_type;
  using edge_iterator = GraphTraits::edge_iterator; 
  
  using container_type = GraphTraits::container_type;

private:
  container_type container_;

public:
  // ... details ...

};

struct DefaultGraphTraits {
  using vertex_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using vertex_iterator = std::vector<vertex_type>::iterator;
  
  using edge_type = std::pair<vertex_type, vertex_type>;
  using edge_iterator = std::list<vertex_type>::iterator;

  using container_type = std::vector<std::list<vertex_type>>;
};

struct DirectedGraphTraits {
  using vertex_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
  using vertex_iterator = std::vector<vertex_type>::iterator;
  
  using edge_type = std::pair<vertex_type, vertex_type>;
  using edge_iterator = std::list<vertex_type>::iterator;
  static constexpr bool directed_ = true;

  using container_type = std::vector<std::list<vertex_type>>;
};

using GraphDefault = Graph<DefaultGraphTraits>;
using DiGraph = Graph<DirectedGraphTraits>;
```

What I want is to "inject" properties (such as edge weight, vertex color, etc), possibly multiple properties, only if necessary.

Boost.Graph is like this:

```
typedef adjacency_list< listS, vecS, directedS, no_property,
        property< edge_weight_t, int > >
        graph_t;
```

As of 2000, Boost.Graph was incredibly well-made, but I don't like several things in 2022's perspective:

1. Just instantiating a graph needs five template parameters
2. and we have to set `no_property` even if we don't need to set properties at all
3. It seems to be able to set only one property for vertex and one property for edge. What if I want to have edge color, edge weight, and edge flow at the same time?

So I want to know how to conditionally "inject" member variables when additional template arguments `Properties` are at present

What I want is like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct EdgeWeightProperty {
  using property_type = T;
};

struct EdgeColorProperty {
  using property_type = int;
};

using MyGraph = Graph<DefaultGraphTraits, EdgeWeightProperty<float>, EdgeColorProperty>;
```

I want `MyGraph` automatically generates member variables something like `std::unordered_map<edge_type, EdgeWeightProperty<float>::property_type>` and `std::unordered_map<edge_type, EdgeColorProperty::property_type>` at compile-time.

What modern C++ design pattern should I use?

Comment: Have you tried std::conditional?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. No, std::conditional_t doesn't fit well in my case. I thought I almost got a clue, I'm using multiple inheritance with variadic template arguments

Comment: "doesn't fit well in my case* i don't really see what's wring with it

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/278432/c-graph-class-with-multiple-property-maps This is my current design, I think it works for now (but should be improved further)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the maps in a `tuple`. If you don't mind changing from `unordered_map` to `map`, it could be done like this:

```cpp
template <typename GraphTraits, typename... Properties>
class Graph {
public:  
  using vertex_type = GraphTraits::vertex_type;
  using vertex_iterator = GraphTraits::vertex_iterator;
  
  using edge_type = GraphTraits::edge_type;
  using edge_iterator = GraphTraits::edge_iterator; 
  
  using container_type = GraphTraits::container_type;

  static constexpr size_t property_count() { return sizeof...(Properties); }

  // get property map by `get<index>()`:
  template<size_t I> auto& get() { return std::get<I>(properties_); }
  template<size_t I> const auto& get() const { return std::get<I>(properties_); }
  
private:
  container_type container_;
  std::tuple< std::map<edge_type,
                       typename Properties::property_type>... > properties_;

public:
  // ... details ...
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6odo5rcxT)

If they must be `unordered_map`s, you need to write hashers for all your `edge_type`s. Using `std::pair<A, B>` as a *Key* in a `map` works out of the box though since `operator<` is defined for types where `A` and `B` also have `operator<` defined.